# Two Xsessions, Two Displays and Chromuim

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, multiple-monitors, chromium

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04. I have a computer on my network that is set up to run two different xsessions with each running Chromium and displaying different web pages on different (1280*1024) monitors. I do not have a mouse or keyboard connected to this computer. To access it I SSH in.

I've got two problems:

1. On the second monitor I get a black strip down the right hand side of the screen. The Chromium window fits in the displayed area and is not cut off at all. The other monitor runs with a full screen. How can I make the black strip disappear and use the whole screen?
2. Because I don't have a keyboard or mouse connected to the computer, i use 
   /etc/init.d/gdm restart 
   to restart the displays. This results in the "Chromium didn't shut down correctly..." message. How can I suppress this or make it so Chromium does shut down correctly?

here's my xsession file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run firefox and point to our dashboard
#exec /usr/bin/firefox -width 1024 -height 1280 -URL "localhost"
MYDISPLAY=$DISPLAY
echo $DISPLAY >> test.txt
date >> test.txt
#export DISPLAY=":0.0"
#/usr/bin/unclutter -idle 5 &
#/usr/bin/chromium-browser --screen 1 --start-maximized --bwsi "http://localhost/status" &
#DISPLAY=:0.1  firefox "http://10.16.14.116:8080/job/Nightly/lastCompletedBuild/testReport/?auto_refresh=true" &
DISPLAY=:0.1 /usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-maximized --bwsi --app --user-data-dir=~/.chromium2 "http://localhost/dash2" &

#export DISPLAY=":0.1"
/usr/bin/unclutter -idle 5 &
#DISPLAY=:0.1 gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-maximized --bwsi --app "http://localhost/status/status-device"
#exec gnome-session
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

UPDATE: I did apt-get update and upgrade, and a restart. It is now full screen on both monitors. No luck with getting rid of the "didn't shut down properly message"

Answer (score 1):

As for the "didn't shut down properly": you're indeed shutting it down the "hard" way: when you restart gdm, all its child processes are killed instantly (with `kill -9`); what you could do is run this:

```
killall chromium-browser
```

which will send a `kill -TERM` to every `chromium-browser` process. This is the "soft" way to close a process - it gets a chance to clean up ; in the case of Chromium, it exits cleanly and doesn't show that annoying message on next start. Just to be on the safe side, you may want to wait a few seconds between the killall and gdm restart:

```
killall chromium-browser
sleep 10
/etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

Tested with Chromium 9 on Ubuntu 10.04.2 .

Answer (score 0):

Did apt-get update and upgrade, and a restart. It is now full screen on both monitors. No luck with getting rid of the "didn't shut down properly message"

Comment: That's an useful addition to the question; could you please edit it into the question, instead of posting as an answer? Thanks.